# foreach loop with 300k iterations freezes at .combine time with massive RAM usage, R

Tags: r, ubuntu, foreach, ram, rbind

I'm facing a real problem in the analysis of my data. I hope someone of you can help me.

I have 18 variables and a binary outcome. I want to try all the possible combinations of variables (i.e. 2^18 -1 = 262'143) and for each one of them to build three models (Logistic, SVM, RandomForest) and to compute the AUC.

A single iteration lasts about 10s and I have a fairly good computer (12 cores + HT, 160GB RAM), so I implemented the following parfor loop (fitData is a dataframe with all the covariates and the outcome)

```
cl <- makeCluster(15, outfile="")
registerDoParallel(cl)

clinicalSweep3 <- foreach (kei= 1:(2^(length(varNames)) -1), .combine='rbind', .packages=c('e1071','pROC','randomForest')) %dopar% {
  varNamesKei <- varNames[as.logical(intToBits(kei)[1:(length(varNames))])]
  yString <- (paste(as.integer(intToBits(kei)[1:(length(varNames))]),collapse=""))
  yLabel <- as.character(paste(varNamesKei,collapse="+"))

  covPacket <- data.frame(t(strsplit(yString,"")[[1]]))
  colnames(covPacket) <- varNames

  AUC_Logit <- NA
  AUC_SVM <- NA
  AUC_RF <- NA

  AUC_Logit2CV <- NA
  AUC_SVM2CV <- NA
  AUC_RF2CV <- NA

  predLogit <- 1:dim(fitData)[1]
  predSVM <- 1:dim(fitData)[1]
  predRF <- 1:dim(fitData)[1]
  for (k in 1:dim(fitData)[1]){
    predLogit[k] <- predict(glm(as.formula(paste("outcome ~ ", paste(varNamesKei, collapse= "+"))),data = fitData[-k,], family=binomial(link='logit')),type="response", newdata = fitData[k,,drop=F])
    predSVM[k] <-   predict(svm(as.formula(paste("outcome ~ ", paste(varNamesKei, collapse= "+"))),data = fitData[-k,], kernel = "linear", cost = 10, type = "C-classification"), newdata = as.data.frame(fitData[k,,drop=F]))
    predRF[k] <-    predict(randomForest(as.formula(paste("outcome ~ ", paste(varNamesKei, collapse= "+"))),data = fitData[-k,], ntree=100),type="prob", newdata = fitData[k,,drop=F])[2]
  }

  AUC_Logit <- auc(fitData$outcome,predLogit,direction="<", levels = c(F,T))
  AUC_SVM <- auc(fitData$outcome,predSVM,direction="<", levels = c(F,T))
  AUC_RF <- auc(fitData$outcome,predRF,direction="<", levels = c(F,T))

  predLogit <- 1:dim(fitData)[1]
  predSVM <- 1:dim(fitData)[1]
  predRF <- 1:dim(fitData)[1]
  for (k in 1:(dim(fitData)[1]/2)){
    predLogit[c(2*k-1,2*k)] <- predict(glm(as.formula(paste("outcome ~ ", paste(varNamesKei, collapse= "+"))),data = fitData[-c(2*k-1,2*k),], family=binomial(link='logit')),type="response", newdata = fitData[c(2*k-1,2*k),,drop=F])
    predSVM[c(2*k-1,2*k)] <-   predict(svm(as.formula(paste("as.numeric(outcome)-1 ~ ", paste(varNamesKei, collapse= "+"))),data = fitData[-c(2*k-1,2*k),], kernel = "linear", cost = 10, type = "eps-regression"), newdata = as.data.frame(fitData[c(2*k-1,2*k),,drop=F]))
    predRF[c(2*k-1,2*k)] <-       predict(randomForest(as.formula(paste("outcome ~ ", paste(varNamesKei, collapse= "+"))),data = fitData[-c(2*k-1,2*k),], ntree=100),type="prob", newdata = fitData[c(2*k-1,2*k),,drop=F])[,2]

  }

  AUC_Logit2CV <- auc(fitData$outcome,predLogit,direction="<", levels = c(F,T))
  AUC_SVM2CV <- auc(fitData$outcome,predSVM,direction="<", levels = c(F,T))
  AUC_RF2CV <- auc(fitData$outcome,predRF,direction="<", levels = c(F,T))

}

cat(as.character(Sys.time()),"combo",yString,"done! (",kei,")\n")

data.frame( yString, covPacket,
            AUC_Logit, AUC_SVM,AUC_RF ,
            AUC_Logit2CV, AUC_SVM2CV, AUC_RF2CV ,
            yLabel)

}
```

Now, the code run for about 30h without problems, even though I noticed the RAM was steadily increasing. Yesterday I decided to create a 100GB swap area and, indeed, when the last worker finished the situation was the following.

[image: RAMUsage]

The CPU was no more used but the R session was still blocked and working.
I hoped it finishes overnight, but this morning the situation is not better.

[image]
The swappiness is set to 50.

Now I got that foreach should not be used with so many iterations.

Now the questions:

1) Should I stop and rewrite the entire code nesting a normal loop inside the foreach? (about 3000 iterations in foreach * 100 in normal for). Or should I wait (maybe increasing the swap)

```
clinicalSweep3 <- foreach (kei1= 0:floor((2^(length(varNames)) -1)/100), .combine='rbind', .packages=c('e1071','pROC','randomForest')) %dopar% {
  for (kei2 in 1:min((2^(length(varNames)) -1) - kei1*100,100 ) ) {
    kei <- kei1*100+kei2
```

# EDIT: I found that probably  foreach( kei=idiv(2^(length(varNames)) -1, chunks=100),...) should do the work

2) Why this massive RAM usage and how to avoid it? (it's all in the main rsession, not in the workers). Should I run gc() at the beginning/end of each iteration? ( default .export = NULL should not import everything in the main thread form workers )

3) Why is my kernel (from ubuntu 20.04 Desktop) not swapping enough? Maybe because it's a single thread with 300GB?

4) If you have suggestions on how to improve the overall performance of the code I'll be glad to hear them!

Thank you!